# Large image HTML5 Canvas poor performance on scale

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to scale my (large: 16200x8100) image using the canvas context; `ctx.scale()`, however I seem to find a very large delay between frames when I start animating with the canvas scaled appropriately to fit the entire image vertically, yet I don't find this problem if I don't start with the canvas scaled at all. Is there some reason for this or solution? Or is it the sheer size of the image?

```
image.onload = () => {
    //the multiplier by which to scale the canvas context to fit image in canvas vertically
    minScale = (canvas.height/image.height);
    ctx.scale(minScale, minScale);
    leftMostOffset = {x: -image.width, y: 0};
    animate();
}


function animate(){

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.save();

    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.clientWidth, ctx.canvas.clientHeight);

    ctx.restore();

    ctx.drawImage(image, rightMostOffset.x, rightMostOffset.y);
    ctx.drawImage(image, leftMostOffset.x, leftMostOffset.y);

}
```

Comment: should your starting image be so large - will any monitor need such a large image?  If not then you should reduce it's size and optimise it for web

Comment: I feel like you're going to run into many issues using such a large image. I suspect a lot of mobile devices will run out of memory loading an image that size...

Comment: If you scale the image to fit then the whole image is required to render it, this may require some GPU<>CPU RAM swapping (which will kill the frame rate). Rendering only part of the image will only need that part and thus there is not as much GPU RAM needed. Draw the large image scaled to fit the canvas to an offscreen canvas (ONCE) and then render that canvas to the display canvas

Comment: The size of the image is  because I am rendering a map of the world that I need to be scalable (for viewing details).  But you're right, this isn't optimal. 
@Blindman67 Thanks for this explanation and solution, I will look into it. I suppose the fact that it stops lagging after several scaling transformations is because it's cached in some way?

Answer (score 2):

The large image will cause RAM to be moved from the CPU to the GPU. This is very slow.

Create a copy of the image at the resolution of the canvas and draw that when you animate. This will be slow on the first two frame as that memory still needs to be moved. But once done the scaled image should render with no slowdown

```
var imageC;
image.onload = () => {
    //the multiplier by which to scale the canvas context to fit image in canvas vertically
    minScale = (canvas.height/image.height);

    leftMostOffset = {x: -image.width, y: 0};
    imageC = document.createElement("canvas");
    imageC.width = ctx,canvas.width;
    imageC.height = ctx.canvas.height;
    imageC.ctx = imageC.getContext("2d");
    imageC.ctx.scale(minScale, minScale);
    // will be slow for first two frames
    imageC.ctx.drawImage(image, rightMostOffset.x, rightMostOffset.y);
    imageC.ctx.drawImage(image, leftMostOffset.x, leftMostOffset.y);
    animate();
}


function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imageC,0,0);

}
```